# Binding specific xml data to a DropDownList

Tags: xml, dropdownlistfor

I have an xml file which reads like below

```
<root>
    <rootnode Value="countries">
        <nodeitem Vaue="India" desciption="0"> </nodeitem>
        <nodeitem Vaue="Pakistan" desciption="1"></nodeitem>
        <nodeitem Vaue="China" desciption="2"></nodeitem>
        <nodeitem Vaue="Japan" desciption="3"></nodeitem>
        <nodeitem Vaue="Lanks" desciption="4"></nodeitem>
    </rootnode>
    <rootnode Value="state">
        <nodeitem Vaue="TN" desciption="0"> </nodeitem>
        <nodeitem Vaue="AP" desciption="1"></nodeitem>
        <nodeitem Vaue="PUNJAB" desciption="2"></nodeitem>
        <nodeitem Vaue="RAJASTAN" desciption="3"></nodeitem>
        <nodeitem Vaue="GUJARAT" desciption="4"></nodeitem>
    </rootnode>
</root>
```

I have a dropdown list and i want to populate the DropDownList only with the countries from the xml file (i.e the dropdown list has to display only `India,Pakistan,Japan,China`). I have a separate DropDownList for the state data.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far? In order to help you with your problem, you need to show some effort (and code), so that someone can help you. Add you code and someone will tell you where the problem is and how to fix it. What programming language and platform are you using?